# create custom window using iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Will any one please help me in creating custom window using `iframe`; that look likes the dialog or prompt box, but with new colors & images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fine selection of jQuery modal windows](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) that will get you started.